# Embedded Types in Parquet

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

Do parquet support Embedded Types like JSON and BSON as mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#embedded-types). I'm unable to generate parquet embedded types using scala, pyarrow,hive.

Answer (score 0):

The Parquet format itself supports these as type annotations. These annotations are rarely used in Parquet though as they are not really native to a file format. In the end they just mark the field as a binary string and don't expose the nested data natively.

Instead, you should rather encode the nested structure of your data in the schema of the Parquet file itself. This requires though a front-up knowledge of the types and style of nesting of the incoming data. The implementation of this schema then also depends on which engine you chose to write the Parquet files.

Comment: So, i tried importing json data into dataframe and then converted into parquet using scala and pyarrow but in both cases im getting bytearray utf-8 type instead of json logical type. Is there any specific case to get this json logical type as mentioned in documentation??